# SQL SERVER QUERY to MYSQL QUERY

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert this MSSQL QUERY to MYSQL

Query looks like this

```
select tu.FirstName+' '+tu.LastName as name,tg.Name as game_name,tg.Status,tg.UserId,tg.gameid from tblUsers tu    
inner join tblGame tg on  
tu.UserId=tg.UserId where tg.Name LIKE @Name + '%'
```

the same query doesnt return any records when i run it on MYSQL, what is the issue ? It works good on SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', tu.FirstName, tu.LastName) AS name, tg.Name AS game_name,tg.Status,tg.UserId,tg.gameid
FROM tblUsers tu    
INNER JOIN tblGame tg ON tu.UserId=tg.UserId
WHERE tg.Name LIKE CONCAT(tu.FirstName, ' ', tu.LastName, '%')
```

Notes:

- it's case insensitive, I've used upper case just for readability
- I've intentionally used both concat and concat_ws to show them as options

Answer (score 0):

```
select tu.FirstName+' '+tu.LastName as name,tg.Name as
game_name,tg.Status,tg.UserId,tg.gameid from tblUsers tu
inner join tblGame tg on
tu.UserId=tg.UserId where tg.Name LIKE @Name + '%' 

select concat(tu.firstName,' ',tu.lastName) as name, ,tg.Name as
game_name,tg.Status,tg.UserId,tg.gameid from tblUsers as tu
inner join tblGame as tg on
tu.UserId=tg.UserId where tg.Name LIKE concat(@Name,'%');
```

Note that, there is not (for example) `field1+' '+field2`,
There is `concat`, `concat_ws`, and `group_concat`,
read about it, it's super useful.